# Minimum of unconstrained multivariable function

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I am working on an optimization problem, and I am a little bit cofused. I know how to solve the constrained problems – using Lagrangian Multiplier – but what about unconstrained ones? (I know how to solve the problem in Matlab using a derivative-free method.) E.g.,

$$ f(\bar w) = f(x,y,z) = x^2+xy+y^2+yz+z^2-6x-7y-8z+9 $$

Comment: Interestin point. If there is no constraint, then no Lagrange multipliers. Just solve in order that all partial be equal to zero since, being a free minumum, at solution(s) all partials wil be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to apply method of Lagrangian multiplier. But you can still apply it by introducing a dummy variable, say $t=0$. Then you can write
$$\mathcal L(w;t)=f(w)-\lambda t$$

Comment: Thanks, but if there's no need to apply the Lagrangian Multiplier method, then what's the approach for these kinds of problems? Just directly take the derivatives and put them equals to zero?

Comment: @Niousha Yes. You can try my Lagrange function and see what will happen

Comment: I think I got your point, but now that I found the extremum points, how can I say if it's a minimum, or a maximum?

Comment: You can consider the Hessian.

Comment: @Niousha A general method is to compute the Hessian at that point and see the Hessian is positive definite or negative definite.

Answer (score 0):

You really do have to check if
$$
               F(x,y,z) = 2x^{2}+xy+y^{2}+yz+z^{2}-6x-7y-8z-9
$$
has a max, a min, or neither. There's no simple derivative test for 3 variables. There's a trick that can be used to get rid of the cross terms. First, let $x=x'+\alpha y$, and choose $\alpha$ so that the $x'y$ term vanishes:
$$
F(x'+\alpha y,y,z)=(2x'^{2}+4\alpha x'y+2\alpha^{2}y^{2})+(x'y+\alpha y^{2})+y^{2}+yz+z^{2}
$$
$$
-6x'-(7+6\alpha)y-8z-9.
$$
The coefficient of $x'y$ is $4\alpha+1$. Letting $\alpha=-\frac{1}{4}$ does the job and gives
$$
   F(x'+\alpha y,y,z)=2x'^{2}+\frac{7}{8}y^{2}+yz+z^{2}-6x'-\frac{11}{2}y-8z-9.
$$
Similarly, let $z=z'+\beta y$ with $\beta=-1/2$ to obtain
$$
   F(x'+\alpha y,y,z'+\beta y)=2x'^{2}+\frac{5}{8}y^{2}+z'^{2}-6x'-\frac{3}{2}y-8z'-9.
$$
All of the transformations are invertible. So, now you can see that the problem has a minimum, and the minimum is obtained by setting the partial differential equations in $x',y,z'$ to 0. The resulting equations for $x',y,z'$ are trivial:
$$
   4x'-6 = 0, \;\;\; \frac{5}{4}y -\frac{3}{2}=0,\;\;\; 2z'-8=0.
$$
Finally, you obtain $(x,y,z)$ from $x=x'-\frac{1}{4}y$, $y$, $z=z'-\frac{1}{2}y$.

WARNING: Check my algebra. The ideas work, but ... .